# Error when using predict function in statsmodels

Tags: python, statsmodels

I get a `PatsyError` that I am not sure how to resolve, when running a Marginal Regression model in Python. The documentation for the class in `statsmodels` is available [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.genmod.generalized_estimating_equations.GEE.html). I used similar code to create a `GEE` model but when I call the `predict` [function](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.genmod.generalized_estimating_equations.GEE.predict.html#statsmodels.genmod.generalized_estimating_equations.GEE.predict) on it I get the error. I'm a bit confused by the error because I pass the models parameters directly (by making no changes to it) as  arguments to `predict`, as is required.

I use the following code:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
fam = sm.families.Binomial()
mod = sm.GEE.from_formula('ind ~ C(month) + C(l_tv) + C(region) + Sum_bal','ID', data=df, family=fam, cov_struct=sm.cov_struct.Exchangeable())
result = mod.fit()
predictions = result.predict(result.params).to_frame().reset_index()
```

The error that I get is:

```
patsy.PatsyError: Error evaluating factor: NameError: name 'month' is not defined
    ind ~ C(month) + C(l_tv) + C(region) + Sum_bal
          ^^^^^^^^
```

**Edit**: I tried to pass `params` as a df, as suggested in the comments, but I still get the same error.

```
###Converting params into a df, from a series 
params_df = result.params.to_frame().reset_index()
params_df = params_df.rename(columns={params_df.columns[0]: 'Column_names', params_df.columns[1]: 'values'})
params_df = params_df.pivot_table(columns=['Column_names'],values='values', index=params_df.index)
```

I checked the column names in `params`, and they're below. Clearly, it doesn't contain just the column name `C(month)`, so I'm not too sure what change to make here. Since `params` contains the new set of columns associated with the dummies for categorical variables, Im not sure how to change the dataframe of params to just contain the variables in the patsy formula, which seems to be whats expected (i.e. not including the dummy variables):

```
Index(['C(month)[T.10]', 'C(month)[T.11]',
   'C(month)[T.12]', 'C(month)[T.2]', 'C(month)[T.3]', 'C(month)[T.4]',
   'C(month)[T.5]', 'C(month)[T.6]', 'C(month)[T.7]', 'C(month)[T.8]',
   'C(month)[T.9]','C(l_tv)[T.81-90]', 'C(l_tv)[T.> 90]', 'C(region)[SA]' , 'C(region)[CA]', 'C(region)[MN]'],
  dtype='object', name='Column_names')
```

Comment: result.predict needs a dataframe not params as argument, dataframe needs to have the same column names available.

Comment: could you print out the first couple of rows and the head for the dataframe df.  We need to see some of the data to be able to diagnose this problem `print(df.head())` would suffice.

Comment: @Josef Thank you. I passed `params` as a dataframe to `result.predict`, with the same column names, that the exog contains (including the dummies), but I still get the error. I edited my question to include this information. Or do you mean that `params`, in any variable type, shouldnt be passed as the argument?